# Plotting a no-skill model in a precision-recall curve

Tags: machine-learning, python, class-imbalance, precision-recall-curve

I am following this [tutorial](https://machinelearningmastery.com/threshold-moving-for-imbalanced-classification/) to apply threshold tuning using precision-recall curve for an imbalanced dataset

Within the tutorial, a no-skill model is defined as:

> A no-skill model is represented by a horizontal line with a precision
> that is the ratio of positive examples in the dataset (e.g. TP / (TP +
> TN)), or 0.01 on our synthetic dataset. perfect skill classifier has
> full precision and recall with a dot in the top-right corner.

The no skill model is the plotted using this code:

```py
no_skill = len(testy[testy==1]) / len(testy)
pyplot.plot([0,1], [no_skill,no_skill], linestyle='--', label='No Skill')
```

[image]

Within my dataset, the no-skill model would be plotted at precision 0.1, which is the ratio of positive examples in train_y.

But my question is: wouldn't a no-skill model in an imbalanced dataset automatically label all observations as being from the majority class? Seeing as precision = TP/(TP+FP), in this case TPs=0 making precision=0? So shouldn't the no-skill model be plotted at precision=0?

Answer (score 1):

For an explanation using conditional probabilities, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall#No-Skill_Classifiers

For different realizations of Noskill classifiers, see dummy classifiers in sklearn

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the dummy model yielding constant probability for all samples, there are two possible thresholds: either everything is classified as positive or negative. So starting point will be `(1, positive_class_ratio)` and the ending point `(0, 1)` (by convention, as precision is undefined with no positives).

Tutorial version is still reasonable as its AUC conforms with sklearn average precision score for this case.